Mysql is being killed by OOMKiller despite having enough ram
The mysql process seem to have no ram limit. I tried 9gb buffer pool size and it crashed (I have 13 gb ram), now its 7gb and the problem remains. Ram profiling using preformance_schema says it should use no more than 9.6 gb of ram, no variable in performance_schema seem to eat too much memory. But the mysqld process consumes almost 12 gb and grows
The mysql config looks like this:
    [client]
    port = 3306
    socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

    [mysqld]
    user = mysql
    port = 3306
    socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
    mysql_native_password=ON

    # Basic Settings
    basedir = /usr
    datadir = /var/lib/mysql
    tmpdir = /tmp
    pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
    # log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

    # Server Performance
    skip-name-resolve
    max_connections = 3000
    table_open_cache = 4000
    table_open_cache_instances = 8
    thread_cache_size = 50

    # Memory Settings
    innodb_buffer_pool_size = 9G
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 9
    innodb_log_file_size = 2G  # Adjust this based on your transaction log needs
    innodb_log_buffer_size = 64M
    innodb_file_per_table = 1
    innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
    innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
    innodb_thread_concurrency = 16
    innodb_read_io_threads = 8
    innodb_write_io_threads = 8
    innodb_io_capacity = 250
    innodb_io_capacity_max = 500
    innodb_purge_threads = 4

    # Caching and I/O
    # query_cache_type = 0
    # query_cache_size = 0
    tmp_table_size = 256M
    max_heap_table_size = 256M
    # join_buffer_size = 16M
    # sort_buffer_size = 4M
    # read_buffer_size = 4M
    # read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M

    # Character Set and Collation
    character-set-server = utf8mb4
    collation-server = utf8mb4_general_ci

    # Binary Logging - Recommended for Replication and Point-in-Time Recovery
    # log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
    # expire_logs_days = 7
    # sync_binlog = 1
    # binlog_format = ROW

    # Error Log Settings
    # log_error_verbosity = 3

    # Security
    max_allowed_packet = 64M
    sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
    innodb_strict_mode = 1

    # Additional Settings
    performance_schema = ON
    event_scheduler = ON
    default_storage_engine = InnoDB

    # Adjusting InnoDB Autoinc Lock Mode
    innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2

    [mysqldump]
    quick
    quote-names

    [mysql]
    no-auto-rehash

I do not mean that it shouldnt consume more memory than the buffer_pool_size. Using this query I calculate the total ram usage:
SELECT 
    @@innodb_buffer_pool_size AS innodb_buffer_pool_size,
    @@innodb_log_buffer_size AS innodb_log_buffer_size,
    @@key_buffer_size AS key_buffer_size,
    @@tmp_table_size AS tmp_table_size,
    @@max_connections * (
        @@read_buffer_size + 
        @@read_rnd_buffer_size + 
        @@sort_buffer_size + 
        @@join_buffer_size + 
        @@binlog_cache_size + 
        @@thread_stack
    ) AS max_connections_memory,
    (@@innodb_buffer_pool_size + 
     @@innodb_log_buffer_size + 
     @@key_buffer_size + 
     @@tmp_table_size + 
     @@max_connections * (
         @@read_buffer_size + 
         @@read_rnd_buffer_size + 
         @@sort_buffer_size + 
         @@join_buffer_size + 
         @@binlog_cache_size + 
         @@thread_stack
     )) AS total_memory_usage
\G

And the output:
innodb_buffer_pool_size: 6039797760
 innodb_log_buffer_size: 67108864
        key_buffer_size: 8388608
         tmp_table_size: 1000000
 max_connections_memory: 99942400
     total_memory_usage: 6216237632

The output is not the same as from mysqlconfig because I made buffer_pool_size smaller and reduced the max_connections so that it doesnt consume all the memory available.
If the query is correct, it should use maximum around 6.5 gb, but it uses 10, 11 and grows
MySQL Version is 8.4.0

Perhaps you should mention what MySQL version you're running. Memory leaks are being found, fixed, and found again regularly.

@mustaccio I edited my question, the version is 8.4.0

The formula you use for calculating max memory is incorrect. In fact, there is no max memory limit for a MySQL Server. Memory usage can grow in an unbounded way.

@BillKarwin the problem is that I have limited memory and I only need to cache the data from the past days. The data older than a week or two is rarely accessed. Therefore, I don't need a huge cache. My disk space is however very large, basically unlimited. If the ram usage continues to grow, it will be killed and restarted again, which is very undesired. What could I do then to somehow be sure that it wont crash?

Check swappiness. in the OS.  The default tends to swap long before it is necessary.

Monitor the memory size of mysqld. If it grows continuously, you might have a version of MySQL Server with a memory leak bug.
Search https://bugs.mysql.com database for reports of memory leaks that affect the version you are using.
Or contact MySQL technical support. Either Oracle, or another consulting company like Percona. Be prepared to pay for their expertise.
Or get busy with a memory profiler to diagnose a possible memory leak yourself. If you don't know how to use such memory profilers, then this is a good time to learn about them.
If you identify a memory leak, then you might have to use a different version of MySQL Server that is not affected by that bug.
If the memory size goes up and down, instead of growing continuously, then perhaps there is no bug that causes a memory leak, but you just have many queries running concurrently that need a lot of memory. In that case, resize what you can (mostly the innodb buffer pool) to leave enough spare RAM to handle the ebb and flow of query-related memory usage.
You mentioned that you don't need all the data to be accessible in the database, you only need the most recent data. In that case, I would recommend implementing some strategy of archiving data. Take it out of the MySQL instance, and store it in some other manner. For example, compressed dump files.
Or if data are truly not needed any more once they are old enough, then delete them. Why keep an ever-growing collection of data you don't need?

Thanks for your reply! The data older than 2 weeks is needed, though rarely accessed. So I decided to keep it in db, not in buffer pool, but on disk. The weirdest thing is that the memory usage grows slower if I set buffer_pool_size smaller. But it grows, continuously. It never gets smaller, not a single mb. It looks like it grows on some percentage of buffer_pool_size every x hours continuously, without any jumps. On link I did not find any report about memleaks so I will try to profile it myself

You might have encountered a memory leak bug that has not been reported. Good luck with your troubleshooting.

If the buffer pool is 9G then it does not mean that mysql will not consume more memory.
9G is for innodb buffer.
It takes more memory based on connection you make and the query those connections run.
Join buffer
Sort buffer
Temp table etc
So you should calculate the memory based on you

Updated my question so that it is more clear why it is strange and has definetely some problem
